# Error "unification would give infinite type" en haskell

Tags: haskell

Estoy tratando de definir una función que dado un elemento y una lista cuente la cantidad de veces que aparece ese elemento en esa lista, entonces tengo:

```
cuantasVecesAparece :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
cuantasVecesAparece p [] = 0
cuantasVecesAparece p [x:xs] =  if p == x
                                then 1 + cuantasVecesAparece xs 
                                else cuantasVecesAparece xs
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> ERROR file:.\ff1.hs:272 - Type error in application
> *** Expression     : p == x
> *** Term           : p
> *** Type           : [a]
> *** Does not match : a
> *** Because        : unification would give infinite type
> ```

No entiendo porque me esta tomando `p` como una lista.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es el ajuste de patrones que estás utilizando. Estás diciendo que recibe una lista `[x:xs]` de un único elemento, que es otra lista con cabeza `x` y cola `xs`. Utiliza `(x:xs)` en lugar de `[x:xs]`.

Además, te falta el primer argumento en la llamada recursiva:

```
cuantasVecesAparece :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
cuantasVecesAparece _ [] = 0
cuantasVecesAparece p (x:xs) = if p == x
                               then 1 + cuantasVecesAparece p xs 
                               else cuantasVecesAparece p xs
```

Answer (score 0):

El patrón que estás usando infiere que si `[x:xs]` es de tipo `[a]`, entonces `x:xs`, que es una lista, es de tipo `a`, el mismo tipo que `p` que, por lo tanto, también es una lista.

El patrón adecuado sería `(x:xs)` para que tanto `x` como `p` tengan el mismo tipo. Mi consejo es no usar `if`'s en favor de *guardas* en la definición de la función:

```
cuantasVecesAparece :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
cuantasVecesAparece _ [] = 0
cuantasVecesAparece p (x:xs) | p == x    = 1 + cuantasVecesAparece p xs
                             | otherwise = cuantasVecesAparece p xs
```

Aunque habría una forma más efectiva:

```
cuantasVecesAparece :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
cuantasVecesAparece p = length . filter (==p)
```